# Getting InputStream and OutputStream for Channel?

Tags: java, netty

We have a legacy (Java Socket) based application I am trying to convert to Netty. It is going pretty well, but I just ran into a section of code that is relying on getting Input/OutputStreams of the connected Java socket. They use this to read and write data to.

Is it possible to wrap a Channel in an Input/OutputStream? I found references for a ChannelBufferInputStream and ChannelBufferOutputStream on the net but that appears it was for an old version of Netty and is no longer around.

I can't defer the reading/writing into the channel handlers (encode/decode) methods because I need the input/output streams for initialization.

I would like to get/create the input streams in the channelActive method so I can initialize the legacy code.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have nothing like this built into netty as everything is asynchronous. That said you could built it yourself with a custom InputStream / OutputStream implementation

Comment: Thanks. Any examples available? All I’m finding online are references to channelbuffer input and output streams.